# Can a solenoid be used to create resistance in a wire

Tags: current, dc, inductor, electromagnetism

Would it be possible to have a solenoid connected to a DC source be used to "slow down" the current of a separate DC circuit with a wire going through the center of the solenoid with the current travelling in the opposite direction to the magnetic field.

Comment: To reduce dI/dt you consider V/L ratio but if there is also a capacitance in the load current, then it will resonate with some Q. so what do you need or mean to use a solenoid if it does not add much L to the wire.

Comment: I think OP is saying "Solenoid" but really means "Air core inductor".  A solenoid has a plunger that mechanically moves when current is applied.  Doesn't seem like that's what he's interested in.

Comment: ^^^ OF course, the answer doesn't change.  Still "no, you can only do this with AC"

Comment: Sounds almost like you are talking about a saturable reactor aka magnetic amplifier.  This is what was used to control AC current before the days of transistors.  Some are still in use.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be possible to have a solenoid connected to a DC source be used to "slow down" the current of a separate DC circuit with a wire going through the center of the solenoid with the current travelling in the opposite direction to the magnetic field.

There will be capacitative coupling between the two wires, but no magnetic coupling (assuming perfect symmetry of the wire arrangement,  no nearby objects, and negligible spacing between the coil wires).

With DC, no, there will be no effect. However, if there were an AC signal on one, it will induce an AC voltage on the other.

Whether this has any effect on the current flowing through the "receiving" wire depends upon the rest of the circuit. For example, are the two circuits galvanically isolated? Or do they have a common ground, in addition to the capacitative coupling?

For example, if you fed mains power through one wire, and connected the other wire to the input of an which amplifier which is referenced to "earth" ground, you would probably get mains frequency noise at the output of the amplifier. On the other hand, if the amplifier were  battery powered, and physically (and electrically) isolated from ground, you may not.

> Can a solenoid be used to create resistance in a wire

In any case, none of the possible effects would be described by an electrical engineer as "creating a resistance in a wire".

Comment: So if i understand correctly, if the solenoid was connected to an AC source it could essentially speed up and slow down the current in the cable going down the middle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "speed up" or "slow down" the current. However, if you were to run mains power through one wire, and connect the other wire to an amplifier, you would probably get mains frequency noise coming out of the amplifier.